# 'Invalid input values for pname' during table statistics gathering?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When I'm trying to gather table statistics using `GATHER_TABLE_STATS` procedure, I'm getting the following error:

```
ORA-20001: Invalid input values for pname
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 31513
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

The code I'm running to gather statistics is

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats ('OWNER', 'TABLE_NAME');
END;
/
```

My Oracle version is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: What do you get from `select * from all_tables where owner = 'OWNER' and table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'`?

Comment: @Aleksej To avoid any mistake, in `gather_table_stats` procedure, I copy pasted the OWNER and TABLE_NAME values from dba_tables. The actual owner and table_name is different. Your query is returning a row for the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have misspelled `OWNER` or `TABLE_NAME` parameter. Its working fine for me as shown below.

```
SQL> conn jay/jay
Connected.
SQL> select table_name from tabs;

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
ROAD
EVENT
ALL_OBS
ACCOUNT
NVARCHAR2_EMAIL
TABLEA
T2
MYTABLE


8 rows selected.

SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('JAY','ROAD');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Update**

As per the My Oracle Support **Doc:755577.1**, It is possible that the post installation scripts for the patch were not run correctly after a patch was applied.

You may need to reinitialize the `DBMS_STATS` package using `execstat.sql` under `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin` directory. Or reinstall `DBMS_STATS`.
Or you might hit the bug- **Bug 14479079 : ORA-20001 GATHERING STATS AFTER CPU JULY 2012 PATCH**

Comment: Owner and table names are correct. To avoid mistakes, I have copy pasted from `DBA_TABLES`.